# react-native, how to factorize code over many tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use react-native to create ios and android app

I create a test app with TabNavigator working good plus a sidemenu ( the button to open it should be in the top action bar ) and floatings actions buttons (the red circle labeled FAB on the picture). All this code is new defined on first tab : app.js.

Each tab have it's own js file with code and render.

My question is :

**How to get this sidemenu,action bar and floating buttons on ALL tabs without coping all the render code and js functions over all the other tabs Js files.**

[image: example]

when i click on a tab only the green part will change

my App.js

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import {...} from "react-native";
  import { TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
  import Imagetest from "./Photo";
  import ListFlatlist from "./ListFlatlist";
  ...  // importing the other file for the tabs

  import styles from "./css/styles";
  import SideMenu from "react-native-side-menu";
  import Menu from "./Menu";


  class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) { ...  }
    ... 


    render() {
      const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;
      return (
        <SideMenu
          menu={menu}
          isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
          onChange={isOpen => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>

           {/*  my app.js content

           */}  

          // this is floating buttons
          <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
            <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="New Task" onPress={() => console.log("notes tapped!")}>
              <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
            </ActionButton.Item>
          </ActionButton>

          </View>
        </SideMenu>
      );
    }
  }

  const AppNavigator = TabNavigator(
    {
      H: { screen: App },
      f: { screen: ListFlatlist },
      Img: { screen: Imagetest },
      B: { screen: Buttonpage },
      S: { screen: ListSectionlist },
      F: { screen: Fetchpage }
    }  
  );

  export default AppNavigator;
```

If a create new components for sidemenu, action bar and FAB I have to put them on all the tab render, not the cleanest way for me but i don't see other solution now.

Comment: For the FAB you could use a parent Component which renders the FAB with an absolute position and a high z-index value. Haven't tried it, but it could work.

Comment: For the FAB i use  'react-native-action-button', but i don't want to put the render code in all tabs. what did you mean for "parent component" ?

Comment: Thats why I suggested you create a top level component which you use as an index component and renders the TabNavigator and the Fab. Something like this: `render() { return (<View><Fab /><StackNavigator /></View>); }`

Comment: did you have a small example or "template" of this please ?
i didn't see how to do it

Comment: I'll try to create a small repo to show an example.

Comment: thank you very much. too bad facebook didn't put the source code of her mobile application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put an example repo together on [Github](https://github.com/JanPeter/RN-TabStackNavigatorFAB). Thats actually all it needs:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import ActionButton from "react-native-action-button";

import Profile from "./Profile";
import Tab1View from "./Tab1";
import Tab2View from "./Tab2";
import Tab3View from "./Tab3";

const TabView = TabNavigator({
  tab1: { screen: Tab1View },
  tab2: { screen: Tab2View },
  tab3: { screen: Tab3View },
})

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TabView navigation={props.navigation} />
      <ActionButton offsetY={100} />
    </View>
  );
}

Home.router = TabView.router;

const StackView = StackNavigator({
  home: { screen: Home },
  profile: { screen: Profile },
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StackView />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, almost fit  all my need ;) 
please how to add functions and constructor inside Home  ? i tried to change the syntax 'const Home = (props) => {}'

Comment: I'll rewrite the code when I'm coming home later today. Should not be that much work.

Comment: maybe not the most sexy solution but i don't know other way : 
`class MyGlobal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TabView navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        <ActionButton offsetY={100} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
 
const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <MyGlobal navigation={props.navigation} />
  );
}`

Comment: Well, I think it should also work if you use the MyGlobal component as the Home component. You just need to add this line to it: `MyGlobal.router = TabView.router;` after you declare your class. Then you just use the MyGlobal component instead of the Home component, which makes things cleaner and sexier :P

Comment: Nice, at first I thought there is no solution for this, until I saw your answer ;)