# react-navigation Customize component produced by TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, create-react-native-app

Using react-navigation, in order to achieve this:

[image: Output Screenshot]

I am nesting `TabNavigator` inside a `StackNavigator`. Code as follow:

```
const HomeTabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Portfolio: { screen: PortfolioScreen },
    Holding: { screen: HoldingScreen }
  },
  {
    //other configs
  }
)

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  },
  {
    // other configs
  }
)

//in App.js render()
return (
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </View>
  </Provider>
)
```

Now, I need a Floating Action Button on both Portfolio and Holding tabs. I do not want to add it twice in both `PortfolioScreen` and `HoldingScreen` components.

Is there a way where I can customize the `HomeTabs` component produced by TabNavigator? Like giving it extra stuffs to render? Is there a HOC API that I am missing? Something like:

```
class CustomizedHomeTabs extends React.Component {
  onFabPress = () => { // do stuffs }

  render() {
    return (
      <FAB onPress={this.onFabPress}></FAB>
    )
  }
}

export default withTabNavigator(routes, config)(CustomizedHomeTabs) //something like this would be cool!
```

Comment: What extra stuffs to you want to render? Please elaborate.

Comment: the FAB component, as shown in CustomizedHomeTabs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146699/react-native-how-to-factorize-code-over-many-tabs